# Cocos2D 2.0 in Uikit ( OpenGL ) issue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I'm having a big problem which i can't find any solutions so this is why i'm asking for help.

I'm working on a project that contains multiple small apps, most of them were made in UIKit, most of them were made in openGL ES 1.0/1.1 ( not sure ) with the help of some helper functions. I had to develop some games which requires collision detection, and animations so i thought cocos2d would be just fine for this.

I managed to import cocos2d 2.0 and make it functional, choosing the game from the menu will start the director and the cocos2d scenes and when i want to exit it i call [_director end] and it goes back to the menu, which is also made in openGL ES.

The problem is that sometimes, and it occurs mostly random, i get an 0x500 GL error on the director end call, resulting in the menu becoming white, but still responding to touches.

This is the 3rd day in which i'm trying to fix this problem. Here's what i tried:
- as cocos2d 2.0 uses open GL ES 2.0 and my menu was GL ES 1.0 i thought it was a conflict between them so i used cocos2d 1.x, but that gave even more problems, and it should'n conflict as when the cocos2d scene is on screen, the menu's glview is paused.

- i'm also getting these errors when i enabled cocos2d_debug each time cocos2d is started.

  cocos2d: surface size: 0x0

  cocos2d: Failed to make complete framebuffer object 0x0

I literally tried everything i could on the web.

here's the code that i'm using to run/close cocos2d

```
// start cocos2d
    _director = (CCDirectorIOS*)[CCDirector sharedDirector];
    CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)
                                     pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                                     depthFormat:0 /* GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24_OES */               
                              preserveBackbuffer:NO                                             
                                      sharegroup:nil                                                
                                   multiSampling:NO                                         
                                 numberOfSamples:0
   [_director setView:glView];
   [_director setDelegate:self];
   [[_delegate glViewAccess] addSubview:glView]; // the glviewacces is the app menu select view


//stop cocos2d
   [_director end];

   // this call restarts the app menu select view update and draw functions and 
   // releases the current instance of the object used to start cocos2d, 
   // releasing the cocos2d scene as well
   [_delegate unloadApplication];
```

Answer (score 0):

First, don't mix OpenGL v1.1 and 2.0 code. Little kittens *will* die.

Second, don't call `[director end]` - it is really not necessary to completely shut down cocos2d every time, instead simply run `stopAnimation` and `startAnimation` to suspend and resume cocos2d. Calling end is not really well tested and numerous issues can occur if you do.

If that doesn't fix it, post the code how you setup & shutdown cocos2d in your app to get more help.

Comment: i tried that solution as well, but that doesn't dealloc the cocos2d scene, and using `_director popscene` when there's only one scene ends the director.

Comment: i posted the code that i'm using right now, in a edit to the main post

Comment: then just switch to an empty scene. Also compare a regular cocos2d appdelegate, looks like there are some methods missing that are normally used in cocos2d init.